# I want to connect my MIDI keyboard to Ableton Live directly (read below)

Tags: ableton-live

so that I can put notes on the Ableton interface directly with my keyboard.

[image: As in adding rectangles (you know what i mean) directly on this interface]

BTW I have full version of Live 9 Lite on Windows 10, and the keyboard is an Alesis V49.

Comment: What model exactly is the keyboard? There is at least both a V49 and a Q49 version. Usually you plug it into your computer via USB, then add it via system settings (OSX), JACK (Linux, OSX) or in the settings of your DAW of choice.

Comment: It's an Alesis v49

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: I heard a keyboardist mention recently that he uses a MIDI-to-USB cable as that can eliminate the need to download and install drivers for each different keyboard. (He travels to many different churches, and just brings the laptop + audio interface)

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer will let you download drivers from [their site](http://www.alesis.com/products/view/v49). After installing the appropriate software your DAW should recognize the controller automatically. (I'm not sure, since i don't use windows, your specific keyboard, or Ableton.)

Answer (score 1):

Some more instructions at this website ( http://www.alesis.com/kb/article/2046 ) .  Basically, after plugging into USB, you need to choose the keboard as input in Ableton preferences.

Then you create a MIDI instrument track to "accept" that input.

I am typing this without having Ableton in front of me.  I could verify those steps later, but I think that this will help you get started.

Comment: dead link in answer